# Android: Save android.net.Uri object to Database

Tags: java, android, uri, alarmmanager

What i m trying to do is get the selected ringtone from the user, set an AlarmManager alarm to play that ringtone when the alarm goes Off. but I need to save the ringtone in the database so I can reset all the alarms after phone reboot.

my question is what is the best way to save the ringtone Uri to the database to retrieve later?

I tried the followings:

1) save the ringtone title in the DB and then retrieve it and append it to a default ringtone path. but the issue, is that the ringtone might be loaded from a different location
2) Storing the uri scheme, scheme spefici part and fragment and then call Uri.fromParts to create the Uri.
3) create an inputStream, byte[] array from the Uri and saving it as a blob and then reading it back and cast the result to Uri

none of these works.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Store the URI as a string in the database and then load it later.

```
// This will get the uri in a string format
String s = mUri.toString();
```

When you retrieve the string from the database, rebuild the URI like this:

```
// This will decode the string into a URI
Uri mUri = Uri.parse(s);
```

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Uri.decode returns a String not a Uri. I used uri.parse(s) and it returned a Uri but it is not the same as the original one ( lots of missing info and fields). so MediaPlayer does not play it properly and breaks in the prepare.

Comment: In my case, every Uri points to an image in the album. I try to save/restore in this way but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's not working anymore. The `Uri.parse(mUri.toString())` does not the same as mUri. There are no path, query, scheme and many other values of the parsed result. I can't use it to load an image.

Comment: Facing same issue Uri.parse() doesn't return the original Uri. And I am not able to upload the video to the server.