# how to get URI of stored images from db and display in image view

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, bitmap

I am trying to fetch image URL saved in my local sql dB and display it in the image view but some how there is error on my image being null.. i am already reading name of the image and it works perfect but the image uri cant not be displayed, As the URI is being fetch its in String format so need to b decoded first to be displayed.. is there a way to decode it when my cursor fetch URI and decode it send it in list-View  for display.

please see the code below:
----------->>>>>>>>>>the class where the fetched data is being displayed

```
public class NewsFeed_Viewoverlay extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newsfeed_viewoverlay);
        DatabaseHelper helper;
        ImageView list_image;
        VideoView list_video;
        helper= new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        list_image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        list_video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.list_video);

//-------------------------------------------------------------------->>>>>>>>XXXXXXXXXXX<<<<<<<<<<-----------------------
        Cursor cursor = helper.getCursor();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        //setup for MApping in view fields
        String [] fromFieldNames=new String[]{helper.KEY_NAME,helper.KEY_IMAGE};

       //list_image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(helper.KEY_IMAGE));
       // list_video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(helper.KEY_FILE));

        int[] toViewID= new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.list_image};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myadaptor= new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor,fromFieldNames,toViewID );
        ListView mylist= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mylist.setAdapter(myadaptor);


        Log.i("READ-->Path in DB->", "" + helper.KEY_NAME + helper.KEY_IMAGE);

    }
```

---------------------->>>>>>>THE Database class for cursor----------------

```
public void Insert(String imgpath, String vidPath, String name ) throws SQLException {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, imgpath);
    values.put(KEY_FILE, vidPath);
    values.put(KEY_NAME,name);

    db.insert(TABLE_Images, null, values);
    db.close();
    Log.i("INSERTED-->Path in DB->", "" + imgpath);
    Log.i("INSERTED-->Path in DB->", "" + vidPath);
    Log.i("INSERTED-->Path in DB->", "" + name);

}
    public static final String[] KEY= new String[] {KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_IMAGE,KEY_FILE};
public Cursor getCursor()
{
    String where=null; ContentResolver resolver;
    db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    //db.rawQuery("select image , name from images",null);
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select _id, name from images",null);
    Cursor cursor= db.query(true,TABLE_Images,KEY,where,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    if (cursor!=null)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    }
    return cursor;

}
```

please refer any links or at-least tell me if there is alternative.

Comment: What is your image URL, its a URI or webURL?

Comment: first check whether your data base contains image path right? there might be problem with image path..

Comment: @NigamPatro yes it is URI of my image which is saved in gallery and i just save its uri in DB.--excuse the grammar mistake i have edited it now

Comment: Below find the answer posted by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After retrieving the URI from database, you need to parse it into URI format.

```
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("Data you got from db");
```

After that you can show it in `ImageView`.

```
imageView.setImageURI(mUri);
```

Comment: can the same logic be applied on video URI as well ??

Comment: @user3598648 Yes, we need to parse that URI but I doesn't know, how to display video?

Comment: ok your answer for image worked like charm .. thank u for the quick response .. i will see if the same thing can be done on Video URI or i might have to open a new thread .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Store the URI as a string in the database and then load it later.

// This will get the uri in a string format

```
String s = mUri.toString();
```

When you retrieve the string from the database, rebuild the URI like this:

// This will decode the string into a URI

```
Uri mUri = Uri.parse(s);
```

for more info follow the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404275/android-save-android-net-uri-object-to-database)

Comment: my image is stored as string format and i get that in my cursor but the and i should convert it before this cursor-- SimpleCursorAdapter myadaptor= new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor,fromFieldNames,toViewID ); so that it can be passed to my list view with other elements as well---
        ListView mylist= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mylist.setAdapter(myadaptor);

Answer (score 0):

first store image uri in a String variable(like imagePath).
then decode your string variable(imagePath). Then set your imagePath following code:

setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));